# How to have a select box in form populate a input box below using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a requirement for adding values selected in a select box to a input box with the same form and am not sure how to best go about this. The select box contains user email addresses and the input box needs to contain multiple email addresses. The idea is that when you select a email address from the select box it is then added to the input either automatically, or by clicking the add button which reload the page in PHP adding to a variable that is the value of the input box. I have tried to do this by having a form within a form but that does not work is there a better way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: why use php and not javascript to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the select's onchange event, set the inputs value to all of the selected options concatenated together.

Here's some psuedo-code:

```
on select changed {
  str= ''
  for every element
    if checked
      str = str + value + ','
  set input's value to the variable str
```

Again in jQuery:

```
$('select').onchange(function(){
  str='';
  $('option:selected').each(function(){
    str+=this.value+','; });
  $('input:text').value(str); });
```

Edit: Here's what you wanted, without multi-select.

```
$('select').onchange(function(){
  $('option:selected').each(function(){
    $('input:text').val($('input:text').val()+$(this).val()+',');})
  .removeAttr('selected'); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it has given me something to get started with but the issue here is firstly that the str value is re-initiated each time the function is run so it does not concatenate the string (http://jsfiddle.net/tYvQ8/511/). Then secondly what happens if the user selects it by mistake how would I add this to a text button to add the string?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question, I assumed it was a multi-select box, for which my code would work.

For you, you just need to append the selected value to the textbox value, then reset the options to unselected.

Edited code above.

Comment: Many thanks this is the code I have come up with http://jsfiddle.net/tYvQ8/518/ from your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Write this code in the top of the page before DOCTYPE.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $previous_email = $_POST['txt_email'];
    $emails = $_POST['select_email'].",".$previous_email;
}
else
{
    $emails = '';   
}
?>
```

The javascript: you can put it in the head section of your html document

```
<script>
function add_email()
{
    document.getElementById('txt_email').value = document.getElementById('select_email').value +','+ document.getElementById('txt_email').value;    
}
</script>
```

And finally the html:

```
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="" name="myform">
    <select name="select_email" id="select_email" onchange="add_email();">
    <option value="email1@test.com">email1@test.com</option>
    <option value="email2@test.com">email2@test.com</option>
    <option value="email3@test.com">email3@test.com</option>
    </select>

    <textarea name="txt_email" id="txt_email"><?=$emails;?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="add" name="add"/>
    </form>

</body>
```

Hope it helps